# Why does make behave differently when given a absolute path vs a local path for -C option?

Tags: makefile

I am writing a make file to compile code within a source tree. In my make file I have the following:

```
MK = make
CC = g++
PWD = $(shell pwd)
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -Wall
SRCDIR = $(PWD)/src
TSTDIR = $(PWD)/tests


export MK CC SRCDIR TSTDIR CFLAGS

tests:
    $(MK) -C $(TSTDIR)
```

then in the `TSTDIR`'s directory is another makefile:

```
OBJS = $(notdir $(shell find $(SRCDIR) | grep .o))
IFLAGS = -I$(SRCDIR)

all: ts_tst

%: %.cc $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The output I get from running this is:

```
make  -C <pwd>/tests
make[1]: Entering directory `<pwd>/tests'
g++     ts_tst.cc   -o ts_tst
ts_tst.cc:8:31: fatal error: packets/ts_packet.h: No such file or directory
 #include "packets/ts_packet.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [ts_tst] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `<pwd>/tests'
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

Notice that the g++ command does not match my template in the make file. Now if I remove the `$(PWD)/` from the variables `SRCDIR` and `TSTDIR` I get this instead...

```
make  -C tests
find: ‘src’: No such file or directory
make[1]: Entering directory `<pwd>/tests'
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Isrc  -o ts_tst ts_tst.cc 
ts_tst.cc:8:31: fatal error: packets/ts_packet.h: No such file or directory
 #include "packets/ts_packet.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [ts_tst] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `<pwd>/tests'
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

As you can see, searching the source dir obviously fails cause the path is now local and so it doesn't exist, however the g++ command now matches my template... Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: BTW. `PWD` is not needed as make already has `CURDIR` (and `CURDIR` is also rarely needed as all paths are relative to the current directory by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
OBJS = $(notdir $(shell find $(SRCDIR) | grep .o))

%: %.cc $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

When `SRCDIR` is set it may find some object files (by the way, I don't know why you are using `grep` here instead of just adding `-name \*.o` to the `find` command: the `grep` is buggy as it will match files such as `foo.ohno` as well).

Suppose it finds the object file `/my/path/to/src/foo.o`.  The `notdir` is run on that and `OBJS` is set to `foo.o`.

That means that the pattern becomes:

```
%: %.cc foo.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Now make wants to search for a pattern rule that will match.  It will not match this rule because although the patterns `%` and `%.cc` match, the other prerequisite `foo.o` does not exist (it's not here in the local directory).  As a result this pattern is ignored and make will keep looking for another pattern.  It will find the built-in pattern, which matches, and that's why you get the output you do.

In the case where no object files are found (wrong `find` command) the `OBJS` variable is empty so the pattern rule matches.

If you remove the `notdir` it should work, but I don't know why you added it so maybe something else is a problem.

Other notes:

- You should always use `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` explicitly when invoking recursive make, and never `make` or some other variable.
- In general you should use `:=` when invoking `shell` or other slower functions.
- It may have been simpler to understand what is happening if you used an explicit rule rather than a pattern rule to build the test program: then you'd get an error like *no rule to build foo.o*

Comment: Thank you, I dind't realize that dependencies could cause a target to not match if there is a problem with them. Once I realized this I came to the exact same conclusion. The solution was in fact to remove notdir

Comment: To be clear, an _implicit rule_ (like a pattern rule) will not match unless all prerequisites match, including non-patterns.  Since many different implicit rules can exist to build the same target (consider how many ways there are to construct a `.o` file!) if one implicit rule doesn't match make will simply look for another one.  Only if none match will you get an error.  For _explicit rules_ if not all prerequisites can be created, make will fail immediately.

Comment: The way make works is before it tries to build any target it will make sure all prerequisites are up to date.  If one or more of them can't be brought up to date (don't exist / can't be created), then that implicit rule doesn't match (or explicit rule fails).